# Updating nested array in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, state

While the onChange works as expected the features are not being updated in state. After many attempts I thought id ask as I'm having trouble finding examples similar to what I'm trying to do.

Array of objects (In this case one object for simplicity sake)

```
const data = [{
    name: 'Starter',
    featured: false,
    price: { Monthly: '$49', Quarterly: '$129', Annually: '$379' },
    description: 'You’re new to the gym but want to do it right.',
    button: {
      label: 'Subscribe',
      href: '/register',
    },
    features: ['Full gym access'],
    logomarkClassName: 'fill-gray-300'}]
```

Map

```
{plans[0].features.map((feature, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <input
      value={feature}
      onChange={(e) => {
        feature = e.target.value
        setPlans([...plans])
      }}
    />
  </div>
))}
```

I am able to update the price object using the code below but having trouble with features as it is an array.

```
onChange={(e) => {
  plans[0].price.Annually =
  e.target.value
  setPlans([...plans])
}}
```

UI

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly is the logic of _updating_ `features` array (do you want to simply append new items? to all or only certain `data` items? should duplicates be considered somehow?).

Comment: @YevhenHorbunkov I added screenshot that maybe explains it better every time the features value changes it should update in state and the new value displayed.

Comment: the button might be an "Update", not "Create" since this is a UI to edit selected gym membership right? How about the flow? can you tell us a bit about the workflow? I think you are not showing us the original one specifically the mapping process

Comment: you should always update state in react in **immutable** way, google that

Answer (score 0):

You must have at least two states, **plans** and **selectedPlan**. The **plans** state will keep the whole data and **selectedPlan** that holds the selected membership that will be edited.

The edit form will show the **selectedPlan** and when the user edits the information it should not update the main **plans** state directly but update the **selectedPlan** instead. The **plans** state will only be updated if the user clicks the "Update button" (where your image is shown as a created button).

```
  const updatePlans = useCallback(() => {
    const updatedPlans = [...plans];
    updatedPlans[selectedPlan.id] = selectedPlan;
    setPlans(updatedPlans);
    setSelectedPlan();
  }, [plans, selectedPlan]);
```

Here, we clone the **plans** and update the selected plan with an **id** property as a helper.

To update the features array in a controlled input, you can use **toString()** method at the **value**, and at **onChange** you can split the input.

```
  <input
    value={selectedPlan.features.toString()}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setSelectedPlan((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, features: e.target.value.split(",") };
      });
    }}
  />
```

you can see the minimal example here:

[image: Edit nifty-golick-jhvy35]